# Usage Of the verb "Miss"

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*miss*".  Suppose we have two separate and unrelated situations.  In one situation, a guy forget to take his medication.  In another situation, a guy driving on a road failed to take a turn into a sidestreet.  How should the verb "*miss*" be used to described the two situations?

> 1a  He ***missed*** his medication.
>   1b  He ***missed*** taking his medication.
>   2a  He ***missed*** the sidestreet.
>   2b  He ***missed*** turning into the sidestreet.

Should the a-versions or b-versions be used?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard 1a or 1b used this way. It would be better to stay with *forgot*. I would say:

> He forgot (to take) his medication.

He didn't really *miss* anything. 1a is ambiguous, 1b is technically OK.

2a and 2b are OK.

Comment: I concur. I think the more common wording is, ["He missed a dose,"](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22if+you+missed+a+dose%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) not, ["He missed his medication."](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22if+you+missed+a+medication%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

1a has possible connotations of regret rather than omission - more like he missed his brother after he went to Australia. If it was backed up by a leading or following statement, "He should take his medication daily, but he missed it yesterday" then it would be fine.
1b is good as it stands.

2a, again, in context no problem; on its own could be slightly ambiguous.
2b is fine.

With context, all would be acceptable. As free-standing statements, the b versions are better, simply because they remove any possibility of misunderstanding, however slight.